# React Native: Get a list of StackActions

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I have a probably odd question. I am trying to navigate to a previous page using:

```
const popAction = StackActions.pop({
            n: 1,
        });

this.props.navigation.dispatch(popAction);
```

but it does not work.

So my first idea was to check which pages are registered in StackActions, how can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to simply navigate back, you can use this

```
    import { NavigationActions } from 'react-navigation';

this.props.navigation.dispatch(NavigationActions.back());
```